# Syntax using void pointers for functions and structs in simple kernel on an embedded system

Tags: c, void-pointers, embedded

I'm writing an extremely simple kernel for an embedded systems class.  The board is the TI Stellaris EKI-LM3S8962.  It runs C and has an OLED display.  I am having issues with void pointers and de-referencing them.  Any help is much appreciated.

My very small initial goal is to prove the concept of passing function pointers and struct pointers around.  Is this the way that I access the var batteryState pointed to by the pointer batteryStatePtr which is part of the data struct passed in?

```
void status (void* taskDataPtr) {
    // make a temporary pointer to a Status Data Struct type
    SDS* data;
    // set data equal to the void* taskDataPtr now cast as a SDS pointer
    data = (SDS*)(taskDataPtr);
    (*data->batteryStatePtr)--;
    ...
```

Here is a very stripped down version of my code, the important region can be located by ctrl-f "HERE IS"

```
struct MyStruct {
     void (*taskPtr)(void*);
     void* taskDataPtr;
};
typedef struct MyStruct TCB;
```

The taskPtr points to a function that takes a void* as an arg and has a void* to a data struct.  As a proof of concept I'm starting as small as possible.  There are two functions, status and display.

```
typedef struct DisplayDataStruct {
    uint*  batteryStatePtr;
} DDS;
DDS DisplayData;

typedef struct StatusDataStruct {
    uint* batteryStatePtr;
} SDS;
SDS StatusData;
```

Status decrements the global variable batteryState through the taskDataPtr it is given.  Display concatenates it onto a string and shows it on the OLED.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;

void status (void* taskDataPtr);
void display (void* taskDataPtr);

void delay(uint msDelay);

//  Declare a TCB structure
struct MyStruct {
      void (*taskPtr)(void*);
      void* taskDataPtr;
};
typedef struct MyStruct TCB;

// status var
uint batteryState = 200;

typedef struct DisplayDataStruct {
    uint*  batteryStatePtr;
} DDS;
DDS DisplayData;

typedef struct StatusDataStruct {
    uint* batteryStatePtr;
} SDS;
SDS StatusData;

void main(void)
{
    DisplayData.batteryStatePtr = &batteryState;

    StatusData.batteryStatePtr = &batteryState;

      int i = 0;  //  queue index
      TCB* aTCBPtr;

      TCB* queue[2];

      TCB StatusTCB;
      TCB DisplayTCB;

      StatusTCB.taskPtr = status;
      StatusTCB.taskDataPtr = (void*)&StatusData;
      DisplayTCB.taskPtr = display;
      DisplayTCB.taskDataPtr = (void*)&DisplayData;

      // Initialize the task queue
      queue[0] = &StatusTCB;
      queue[1] = &DisplayTCB;

      // schedule and dispatch the tasks
      while(1)
      {
          for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
             aTCBPtr = queue[i];
             aTCBPtr->taskPtr( (void*)(aTCBPtr->taskDataPtr) );
          }
          systemState = (systemState + 1) % 100;
          delay(50);
      }
}

void status (void* taskDataPtr) {
    // return if systemState != 0 aka run once every 5 sec
    if (systemState) {
      return;
    }
    // make a temporary pointer to a Status Data Struct type
    SDS* data;
    // set data equal to the void* taskDataPtr now cast as a SDS pointer
    data = (SDS*)(taskDataPtr);


    // HERE IS where I am stumped. Is (*data->batteryStatePtr)-- the way you do this????
    // access the batteryStatePtr through the struct data
    // then dereference the whole thing to get at batteryState
    if ((*(data->batteryStatePtr)) > 0) {
      // decrement batteryState
      (*(data->batteryStatePtr))--;
    }
    return;
}

void display (void* taskDataPtr) {
    // run once every 5 sec
    if (systemState) {
      return;
    }
    DDS* data;
    data = (DDS*) taskDataPtr;
    char hold[12] = "Batt: ";
    char numHold[4];
    sprintf(numHold, "%u", (*(data->batteryStatePtr)));
    strcat(hold, numHold);

    // display the string hold
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw(hold, 15, 44, 15);
    return;
}

// use for loops to waste cycles, delay taken in ms
void delay(uint msDelay)
{
      // when i == 60000 and j == 100 function delays for ~ 7.6 sec
      msDelay = msDelay * 150 / 19;
      volatile unsigned long i = 0;
      volatile unsigned int j = 0;

      for (i = msDelay; i > 0; i--) {
             for (j = 0; j < 100; j++);
      }
      return;
}
```

Comment: `(*(data->batteryStatePtr))--` should be fine... is there a particular reason you think there's a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think it's a problem because it doesn't work and my pointer expertise is minimal.  I just wanted to add that syntax into the pile of things-I-know-are-not-completely-wrong.

Comment: Does the compiler give any warnings?  And where is `systemState` declared?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" - what do you expect to see and what do you actually see? Is it that the value does not decrement in the display? Have you verified that it is decrementing in the status task? You may have to make the batteryStatePtr pointers volatile so that the compiler always generates code to read from memory rather than cache the value.

Comment: Make sure you're not missing any header files or sources either... I don't see declarations for `RIT128x96x4StringDraw()` or `systemState` anywhere, or any `#include`'s that aren't standard C RTL headers

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments.  I noticed that just after the sprintf call the pointer value was corrupted.  I wrote my own integer to string function and now it works... mysteriously.  Meta question: is there something I should do with this question as it is non-typical?

Comment: Put your solution in as an answer and accept it. Sprintf can use a lot of stack space. You could try increasing it as another confirmation if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of getting at the value batteryState through the void* structure is correct.  For clarity, here it is:
The data structure called data has a member called batteryStatusPtr.  After getting the ptr, dereference it to get at what it is pointing at.  Add more parenthesis for order of operations. (not 100% sure if those are necessary, but it allows me to sleep at night.  Finally decrement it by 1.

```
(*(data->batteryStatusPtr))--;
```

In one line the problem was after using sprintf() to convert it to a string, and sending it to a display function, the value became corrupted with some strange garbage number.  I don't know why, but sprintf() was the cause.  I wrote my own uint to string function and the problem was solved.  The sprintf worked fine on my linux box, but the Texas Instruments LM3S8962 Lumninary Evaluation Board did not like it.

Here is a stripped down, commented version of the code.  As I'm a bit of a noob (in school, have a year of programming experience in Javascript, not C), I will take no responsibility for any errors.  This is to the best of my knowledge.  Perhaps in the process of stripping it is broken so I apologize in advance.

```
// typedef uint as an unsigned integer for reference
typedef unsigned int uint;

// typedef TCB as a structure with two elements,
// first a address of a function (actually not 100% sure about this one,
//  i'm kinda a noob but I think that's right)
// second a void pointer to a struct that stores data
struct MyStruct {
    void (*taskPtr)(void*);
    void* taskDataPtr;
};
typedef struct MyStruct TCB;

// declare a data struct SDS which holds data for the status function
// there is only one variable in there, a uint* to the batteryState
// called batteryStatePtr
typedef struct StatusDataStruct {
    uint* batteryStatePtr;
} SDS;

// declare the global variable batteryState
uint batteryState;

// declare the function status that returns void and accepts a void* taskDataPtr
void status (void* taskDataPtr);

void main() {

    // declare a status TCB
    TCB StatusTCB;
    // declare a StatusDataStructure called StatusData
    SDS StatusData;

    // set the SDS task pointer to the address of the function status
    StatusTCB.taskPtr = &status;
    // set the SDS task data pointer to the address of the StatusDataStructure
    // which is cast as a void pointer
    StatusTCB.taskDataPtr = (void*)&StatusData;

    // declare a TCB pointer task and point it at the StatusTCB
    TCB* taskPtr = &StatusTCB;

    // call the status function through the TCBPtr and send it the dataStruct
    // associated with that TCB (StatusData)
    TCBPtr->taskPtr( (void*)(TCBPtr->taskDataPtr) );
}

void status (void* taskDataPtr) {
    // make a temporary pointer to a Status Data Struct type
    SDS* data;
    // set data equal to the void* taskDataPtr now cast as a SDS pointer
    data = (SDS*)(taskDataPtr);
    // access the global variable batteryState through the data struct associated
    // with the status TCB, of type SDS
    // decrement it if greater than 0
    if ((*(data->batteryStatePtr)) > 0) {
        (*(data->batteryStatePtr))--;
    }
}
```